# How do i determine the direction of components of electric fields?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

[image: Here is an image of my textbook describing an electric field problem]

[image: Here is another image]

Here are images of some of the pages inside my textbook that show a strategic problem, it gives me 2 charges and a point at which we would detect the electric field but i have a problem with solving it.

I understand that the charge of the field lines depend on the positivity or negativity of a charge, but what I do not understand is how to figure out from the components of a field line (x and y components for E2 for instance) the directions.

According to the second image, for E2, the x component is positive? but why? isn't it approaching the negative charge as well as the y component of E2 is?

Please guide me through this I really need help, have a finals test tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since $q_2$ is negative, the direction of $E_2$ is always pointing at the charge $q_2$. obviously the $x$ component of $E_2$ is positive.

Comment: Aren't components supposed to be negative when they aim towards negative charges and positive when they aim outwards from positive charges?

Comment: How though? could you explain why it is positive?

Comment: Wait so it doesnt actually depend on the charge?

Comment: Oh okay because i thought it determined the freaking electric fields, thank you so much dude you're a life saver omg!